# ASP.Net MVC4 Web Api with Help Page of WCF possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am starting to develop with Web Api MVC 4 and created the whole stack. My services are working but I wonder if it is possible to see a Help Page similar to what exists on WCF.
Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently but this is in the MVC 4 roadmap:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%204%20RoadMap

> Web API Help page generation: We want to make it easy to generate rich, web-based documentation 
>   for your web APIs, including the resource URIs, the allowed HTTP methods, expected parameters, and 
>   sample message payloads.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the ASP.NET Web API Help Page which is available as a NuGet package:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/08/15/introducing-the-asp-net-web-api-help-page-preview.aspx